# Ruby - can't install sanitize gem, Nokogiri dependency

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, sanitize

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.2, trying to install the sanitize gem and I get the error below. I have read that there are problems of some sort with the Nokogiri gem and Xcode. What can I do to fix this?

Alternatively, is there another gem that I can use to strip the html away from a string? (I just want the content).

```
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: Nokogiri itself can do the job.. With a bit of _Xpath_ and _CSS_ knowledge. I used it a lot.

Comment: How you were trying to install this Gem ?

Comment: just a standard 'gem install sanitise'... Should i be doing something else?

Comment: Just do follow -- http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x